# Remove duplicates and replace from an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of elements:

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "one"]
```

I want to replace duplicates with empty strings in array:

```
output= ["", "", "three", "", "", ""]
```

Here is my code:

```
let obj = {}

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   let a = arr[i];
   if(obj[a]) obj[a]+=1
   else obj[a]=1
}

let output = []

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   output[i] = obj[arr[i]] > 1 ? "" : arr[i];
}
```

Is this a better approach or is there a way to improve the performance?

Comment: If this code works, and you are simply asking if there is a better approach, then this question is off topic for StackOverflow.  If this is the case it would be more appropriate on codereview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code using `reduce` and `map`, but there aren't really any optimizations that could be made.

```js
let arr = ["one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "one"];
let freq = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1, acc), {});
let res = arr.map(x=>freq[x] === 1 ? x: '');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ternary operator you forgot to assign the output array to expected value so it should be

```
 output[i] = objx[arr[i]] > 1 ? output[i]="" : output[i]=arr[i]
```

```js
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "one"]


 obj = {}

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   let a = arr[i];
   if(obj[a]) obj[a]+=1
   else obj[a]=1
}
let output = []

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   output[i] = obj[arr[i]] > 1 ? output[i]="" : output[i]=arr[i]
}

console.log(output)
```

Here is a different simpler approach using `foreach` and `map`

```js
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "one", "two", "one"]

 var obj = {}  ;
arr.forEach(e => {
  obj[e] = obj[e] || 0
  obj[e] =  obj[e] + 1
})
res= arr.map(x => obj[x] > 1 ? "" : x)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: downvoter please feel free to comment why my answer is incorrect, I would like to learn from my mistakes :) thanks